# MySQL Database with Wildfly 10, filters and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I use a Wildfly 10 application server and need to create an application with a REST-part and a ejb part. In the ejb is the persistence.xml to access a datasource. In the war the EJB gets injected. Additional to that I have a client which connects to the Bean with JNDI.

Bean:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(SampleBeanRemote.class) 
public class  SampleBeanRemoteImpl implements SampleBeanRemote  
{
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="workingdb")
  private EntityManager em;

  //methods to access via JNDI (for example em.persist(), em.find, etc.)
}
```

I need to have filters on a ejb POJO (OneToMany) so I thought I would need Hibernate to do this. I've read so much now about entityManagers, sessions, factories, BMTs, CMTs that I don't really now what to do anymore. How can I set this up properly?

EDIT:
OneToMany:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "arbeitsgaenge")
@FilterDef(name="userFilter", parameters={
        @ParamDef( name="akuser", type="integer")
})
public class Arbeitsgang implements java.io.Serializable
{
    /*
     * FIELDS
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3812458124424219088L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int sollZeit;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String modul;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Timestamp.Status status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_auftrag", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Auftrag auftrag;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @Filter(name = "userFilter", condition="user = :akuser")
    @JoinColumn(name="id_arbeitsgang")
    private List<Timestamp> timestamp = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_arbeitsgang_ps")
    private List<Progstat> progstat = new ArrayList<Progstat>();

    /*
     * CONST
     */

    public Arbeitsgang(int sollZeit, String name, String modul, Timestamp.Status status, Auftrag auftrag) 
    {
        this.sollZeit = sollZeit;
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.auftrag = auftrag;
        this.setModul(modul);
    }

    public Arbeitsgang(int sollZeit, String name, String modul, Auftrag auftrag) 
    {
        this(sollZeit, name, modul, Timestamp.Status.NA, auftrag);
    }

    public Arbeitsgang(int sollZeit, String name, String modul) 
    {
        this(sollZeit, name, modul, Timestamp.Status.NA, null);
    }

    public Arbeitsgang()
    {   }

    /*
     * GETTERS
     */

     .....

    /*
     * SETTERS
     */

     .....

    /*
     * GENERAL
     */

    public void addTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp)
    {
        this.timestamp.add(timestamp);
    }
}
```

ManyToOne:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timestamp")
public class Timestamp implements java.io.Serializable
{
    /*
     * FIELDS
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6478056732010632092L;

    public static enum Status { 
        NA, STARTED, PAUSED, RESUMED, FINISHED
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long zeit;
    private long overwrite;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_arbeitsgang", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Arbeitsgang arbeitsgang;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private User user;

    /*
     * CONST
     */

    public Timestamp(long zeit, long overwrite, Status status, Arbeitsgang arbeitsgang, User user) 
    {
        this.zeit = zeit;
        this.overwrite = overwrite;
        this.status = status;
        this.arbeitsgang = arbeitsgang;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Timestamp()
    {   }

    /*
     * GETTERS
     */

     ....

    /*
     * SETTERS
     */

     ....
}
```

So basically, one "Auftrag" has many "Arbeitsgaenge", which has many "Timestamps" and I want all of the "Arbeitsgaenge" but only the "Timestamps" which have a certain user id.

Comment: Can you post the code of your POJO then we can help you with the DOA code and annotations to use with Hibernate so you can interact with the database through your EntityManager

Comment: I have added the pojos. Sorry about the delay!

Comment: if you still have a problem, take a look at https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee6 , it has inside both entities and jax-rs, and it is functional (though unfinished, it has some bugs), and it runs on wildfly.

Comment: Thank you, I've done it similar, but got some improvements.